# lazy sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting

**I have a huge list and want to get the top n elements. Fast.**

In other languages one can retrieve those elements in linear time using lazy evaluation with `take` and insert sort or something similar.
However Python's `sort` and `sorted` functions always sort the whole list which will take very long.

Is there a fast solution by using built-in functions or do I really have to write my own generator for this task?

Comment: "In other languages one can retrieve those elements in linear time using lazy evaluation with `take` and insert sort or something similar." - what? No, you'd use something like introselect, and it'd give you the top n elements, but not in any particular order. (You can't get the top n elements in sorted order in linear time with a comparison-based approach, because taking n=the input length would sort the whole input in linear time.)

Comment: Heapq is the canonical way of doing the exact thing that was asked about. However, just in case you actually wish you had a sorted list at all times, https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/ or sortedcollections may be what you want. It keeps the list sorted with not a lot of overhead, in particular it is fairly good at avoiding large allocations.

Comment: This is rather old, but just as a clarification: The heapq approach is often wrapped as a lazy sequence in sorted languages, meaning you can "take k (sort x)" with O(n + k log n) complexity, which is linear-time for fixed "k".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can heapify the list with the `heapq` package. This happens in linear time. Then you can extract elements from that heap in logarithmic time. If there are not many of them that you need to pull, it will be more efficient than sorting the whole list first.

Here is a short illustration:

```
import heapq

lst = [5,2,6,8,3,4,9,2,1,0,11,0,7]

heapq.heapify(lst)  # O(n)

while lst:
    print(heapq.heappop(lst))  # O(logn)
```

If you know up front how many values you need, then you can get them in one call, without the need to explicitly call `heapify`. Let's say you need 4:

```
import heapq

lst = [5,2,6,8,3,4,9,2,1,0,11,0,7]
print(*heapq.nsmallest(4, lst))
```

Note that this will not mutate `lst`.

Comment: Could you not just use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) directly on the list?

Comment: Yes, indeed. that is even better in case you know up front how many you need. Added to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of [`numpy.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy.partition).  Example:

```
import numpy

partitioned_array = numpy.partition(numpy.array(my_huge_list), len(my_huge_list) - n)
```

The result is a copy of the whole input, as a numpy ndarray, with the *n*<sup>th</sup> largest element *n* positions from the end and all larger elements following it.  If you want these elements in sorted order then you can separately sort just that slice.

`numpy.partition` uses the Introselect algorithm, and it runs in O(n) time.  It creates a copy of the whole input, occupying O(n) space, but otherwise has O(1) overhead.  It does not reorder its input.

**Alternatively**, if your *n* is bounded by a smallish constant, it might make sense to just implement the selection by hand.  Something like this might do:

- start with a list, *L*, containing the first *n* elements of the huge list, in sorted order
- scan once through the remaining elements of the huge list.  For each one, insert the element into *L* such that *L* remains sorted, and drop the smallest element

When that finishes, *L* contains the largest *n* elements from the huge list, in sorted order.

Because *L* never exceeds *n* + 1 elements, this approach performs O(*nm*) steps, where *m* is the length of the huge list.  If *n* is bounded by a constant then that reduces to O(*m*).  Additionally, this approach neither reorders the original list nor makes a copy of it, and it has O(1) space overhead, plus the O(n) size of the result list.  And the result list comes out sorted, in case that's important to you.

A fairly naive implementation could look something like this:

```
import itertools

top = my_huge_list[:n]
top.sort()
for x in itertools.islice(my_huge_list, n, len(my_huge_list)):
    for index, top_val in enumerate(top):
        if top_val >= x:
            index = index - 1
            break
        if index > 0:
            top[index - 1] = top_val
    if index >= 0:
        top[index] = x
```